# Pulseaudio does not register HFP profile in SDP server

Tags: linux, pulseaudio, bluez

I need to pair a headset to a Linux based device over Bluetooth. Actually I want to have mic paired to the device to get raw audio from the mic. 
The device does not have a sound card.

I have installed:

- Bluez 5.15
- pulseaudio 9.0

`sdptool browse local` does not show HFP profile registered.

The pulsaudio wiki says:

> Note: The device may be off by default. Select its audio profile (OFF, A2DP, HFP) in the "Configuration" tab of pavucontrol.

But I have no GUI.

I did Bluetooth pairing through bluetoothctl to the headset but "connect" does not work.

`hcidump` shows that the headset asks for "Audio Gateway service" via SDP and the device reply with empty list. After that The headset starts "connection" over.

1. How to configure pulseaudio? I did not do anything special, just compiled and installed pulseaudio.
2. In the pulseaudio builds directory there's no `module-bluetooth-discover` module. But I see the source `module-bluetooth-discover.c` Somewhere I read that it was recommended to load this module, but I don't have it. How to get it compiled? Or it is inside the binary?

Comment: So, it is turned out that I missed options "--enable-bluez5" and "--enable-bluez5-native-headset" for HSP  or "--enable-bluez5-ofono-headset" for HFP (need oFono)
 in configuration for pulseaudio.